# Как в цикле сделать правильное отображение нескольких CodeMirror?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть 2 одинаковых блока. На одной странице отображается правильно только 1 блок, как сделать, чтобы отображались нормально все? Код прикрепляю:

```
window.onload = () => {
const [input] = document.querySelectorAll(".codemirror-textarea");
const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(input, {lineNumbers: true});}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(e) {
document.querySelectorAll(".codemirror-textarea").forEach(el => {
    const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(el, {lineNumbers: true, readOnly: true});
});}
```